# Debian 10.9 fresh install: network configuration

Tags: debian, network-interface

I have installed Debian 10.9 on a Dell poweredge r710 but was not able to configure network.
Server has 4 physical ethernet ports; all are of Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (Client NDIS VDB) #38-41.
Server firmware version is iDRAC6 Firmware revision version: 1.96.01. Primary Backplane firmware revision 1.07. Thank you.<

I tried the command «

> ip link show

»; below is the output of the command:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:ba:db:17:a9:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:ba:db:17:a9:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:ba:db:17:a9:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:ba:db:17:a9:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I also tried the command «`ping -c 2 8.8.8.8»` and got the following error message:

```
Network is unreachable.
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you put the firmware in a USB pen when installing?

Comment: Yes. I made a bootable USB pen device.

Comment: @cProg that was not the question. What the other user is asking is, did you add the relevant networking firmware to the installer USB drive (or mount a drive/CD that had the firmware during installation)? You should be able to acquire the relevant networking drivers from the networking chipset vendor or Dell if you do not have them on hand.

Comment: I see. No I didn't add the relevant networking firmware to the installer USB drive.

Comment: Anyone knows where to find Debian driver for Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (Client NDIS VDB) network adapter? The Linux driver seems to be not foundable.

Comment: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (Client NDIS VDB) network adapter driver could be downloaded from here: https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-bnx2

Comment: @cProg you should write your own answer for what you did to resolve your own issue. Please try to avoid answering a question within the comments.

Comment: @kemotep, I have not yet tried the solution. I will try it tomorrow, and then If the above comment is the solution, I will post an answer.

Comment: From the output of the "ip link show", the 4 adapters are recognized by the kernel, so you do not need anything extra for the time being. Please check my comments in my answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the output of "**ip link show**" command to find out the names of the ethernet interfaces and then, the simplest way is to edit the **/etc/network/interfaces** file for the configuration.

Check this link for documentation: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: I tried commands «ip link show» and «ping -c 2 8.8.8.8» and have edited my question to put those commands results.

Comment: Can you please provide info on which port(s) are cabled? It seems from the output that the system tried to activate one port (eno1) but you can see a NO-CARRIER flag, which means that there is no cable, or that the cable is not attached to a switch.

Comment: Please run the following command:

`for i in $( seq 1 4 ); do echo "**** eno$i"; ip link set eno$i up; mii-tool eno$i; ethtool -i eno$i; done`

You might get an error message if the mii-tool or the ethtool is not installed. Just copy paste the output.